# How to aviod flickering of div

Tags: jquery

Hi please check the below link on jsfiddle:

```
$(function(){
    $(".but3").click(function(){
        //console.log('Clicked Button 3');
        if($('.slide1').is( ":hidden" ))
        {                       
            $('#main').toggleClass('lopen',1000);
            $('.slide1').toggle();
        }
        $('.slide3').toggle();
        $('#main').toggleClass('ropen',1000);
    });
    $(".but1").click(function(){
        //console.log('Clicked Button 1');                  
        $('.slide1').toggle();
        $('#main').toggleClass('lopen',1000);
    });
});
```

"http://jsfiddle.net/A9mH7/"

My question is whenever I do hide the left/right div's the center div should be automatically risize to the fill width. But here when we're having only the center width(Blue) and left and right div's were hidden when we clicked on left button, the center div flickers. So please do let me know how can I avoid this flicker(shows up after some time) ? and another thing is when click on left button to hide the left div the center div starts reloading from left to right but I need in such a way that it should extend to left as and when the left div hides and the same for right side too.

Please do help me regarding this. Waiting for your answers

Thanks Sathish

Comment: Could you please clean up the code a bit? It will make it easier to understand what you want. Currently, but1 and but3 do different things, and for some reason but3 operates on slide1 and declares lopen. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**Use parent class name too select attribute like this:**

```
$(".slide1 .but1").click(function(){
    //console.log('Clicked Button 1');                  
    $('.slide1').toggle();
    $('#main').toggleClass('lopen',1000);
});


 $(".slide2 .but1").click(function(){
    //console.log('Clicked Button 1');                  
    $('.slide1').toggle();
    $('#main').toggleClass('lopen',1000);
});
```